# iOS - Is there a way to trigger the memory cleaning?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I found that (for example) a UI object, like UIPickerView, is allocated and release frequently, even the corresponding dealloc method is called (proved by using Instruments), the Heap still grows up.

Is there a way to trigger the optimization of the autorelease pool to improve the whole scenario ?

My application needs to take photo, manage photo and upload to server. Over period of time, the Heap grows large and finally it crashes my application. ** I checked that there is no obvious memory leakage *** with the use of Instruments.

Any Help or suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use ARC Feature. There is refractor menu in Xcode to translate your old style to ARC environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own autorelease pool at places which make sense to your application. The following way of creating autorelease pools works with or without ARC.

```
// Stuff you plan to keep around after finishing the block below
@autoreleasepool {
    // Load an image, send to server
}
// The images are released
```

It sounds like it is taking some time for your memory to get out of hand. If you are doing your work in the main UI run loop you should have autorelease occurring very regularly, so I'm not sure that another autorelease pool will help you. Perhaps you are keeping your references in such a way that they are not being released because they could still be used. Many leaks occur because objects are not removed from arrays, sets, and dictionaries.